# any suggestions for speeding-up Java code that clones hash maps?

Tags: java, clone

I have a java class that contains a hash map as a member. This class is created with many objects. In many of these cases, one object of this type is cloned to another object, and then changed. The cloning is required because the changes modify the hash map, and I need to keep the original hash map of the original object intact.

I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions how to speed up the cloning part, or maybe some trick to avoid it. When I profile the code, most time is spent on the cloning these hash maps (which usually have very small set of values, a few hundreds or so).

(I am currently using the colt OpenIntDoubleHashMap implementation.)

Comment: I looked at the code of HashMap and `clone` just starts from scratch, recomputing all hash keys.  You could rewrite a subclass of HashMap, but it would be overkill and there probably is a good reason why they choose such an inefficient `clone`.

Comment: change title to more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use more effective algorithms for it. Look at the http://code.google.com/p/pcollections/ library, the `PMap` structure which allows immutable maps.

*UPDATE*

If your map is quite small (you said only a few hundreds), maybe more effective would be just two arrays:

```
int keys[size];
double values[size];
```

In this case to clone the map you just need do use `System.arraycopy` which should work very fast.

Comment: I like the idea, and theoretically, it is what I need, but using this actually makes my code slower...

Comment: Could you provide some benchmark tests code? Maybe you are doing something ineffective.

Comment: I am setting this to be the answer because it seems to be the closest, and it should work theoretically. Though, pcollections don't seem to help in this case.

Comment: It's still interesting why doesn't it help? I think the main reason is that it's uses objects, while you are using primitive `int`->`double` map. So you have a lot of auto-boxing overhead. Maybe you could re-implement PMap using primitives, should be not very difficult, just a lot of copy-paste and boilerplate code...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe implement a [copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) wrapper for your map if the original only changes occasionally.

Comment: I actually do have copy-on-write here.. It copies the hash map only if one of the methods that change it are used. This does not help much, since most of the hash maps at some point are required to be copied.

Answer (score 0):

If only a small fraction of the objects change, could you implement a two-layer structure:

1. Layer 1 is the original map.
2. Layer 2 keeps the changed elements only.

Any object from the original map that needs to change gets cloned, modified an put into the layer-2 map.

Lookups first consult the layer-2 map and, if the object is not found, fall back to the layer-1 map.